# Import Orders in Magento through CSV

Tags: php, csv, import, magento-1.7

I have used below code. It is working on simple product and single product.

Creating order programmatically for all types of products. First I have added product into the cart, then I have added all parameters to order like shipment, payment method and billing and shipping method accordingly. When I add options to the product it generates blank product order.

But it is not working for other product types.

I used below script also,

http://pragneshkaria.com/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

Please help me to create orders programmatically.

Comment: The link which u have followed is still under development. They directly mentioned that it has some error --- "Still there are limitation in this code."-- This is the sentence at the below of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a module for that,

```
/* create order for registered customer */

$id=12; // get Customer Id
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
// print_r($customer->getData()); exit;
$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
$reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId(1); // exit();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteId(0)
->setGlobal_currency_code('USD')
->setBase_currency_code('USD')
->setStore_currency_code('USD')
->setOrder_currency_code('USD');
// Set your store currency USD or any other

// set Customer data
$order->setCustomer_email($customer->getEmail())
->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
->setCustomer($customer);

// set Billing Address
$billing = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultBilling())
->setCustomer_address_id($billing->getEntityId())
->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
->setCity($billing->getCity())
->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
->setFax($billing->getFax());
$order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

$shipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultShipping())
->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
->setCity($shipping->getCity())
->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
->setFax($shipping->getFax());

$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
->setShipping_method('flatrate_flatrate');
/*->setShippingDescription($this->getCarrierName('flatrate'));*/
/*some error i am getting here need to solve further*/

// you can set your payment method name here as per your need
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
->setMethod('purchaseorder')
->setPo_number(' â€“ ');
$order->setPayment($orderPayment);

// let say, we have 2 products
// check that your products exists
// need to add code for configurable products if any
$subTotal = 0;
$products = array(
    '7088' => array(
    'qty' => 2
    ),
    '7089' => array(
    'qty' => 1
    )
);

foreach ($products as $productId=>$product) {
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$rowTotal = $_product->getPrice() * $product['qty'];
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteItemId(0)
->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
->setProductId($productId)
->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['rqty'])
->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
->setName($_product->getName())
->setSku($_product->getSku())
->setPrice($_product->getPrice())
->setBasePrice($_product->getPrice())
->setOriginalPrice($_product->getPrice())
->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);

$subTotal += $rowTotal;
$order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
->setGrandTotal($subTotal)
->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);

$transaction->addObject($order);
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
$transaction->save();

/* create order for guest customer */

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

$lsit_od_id = array('7125','7088','7089');
foreach ($lsit_od_id as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value); /* 6 => Some product ID */
    $buyInfo = array('qty' => 1);
    $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));
}


$billingAddress = array(
    'firstname' => 'abc',
    'lastname' => 'ccc',
    'company' => 'hhhh',
    'email' =>  'manoj@gmail.com',
    'street' => array(
        'Sample Street Line_1',
        'Sample Street Line_2'
    ),
    'city' => 'City',
    'region_id' => '',
    'region' => 'State/Province',
    'postcode' => '12345',
    'country_id' => 'NL',
    'telephone' =>  '1234567890',
    'fax' => '123456987',
    'customer_password' => '',
    'confirm_password' =>  '',
    'save_in_address_book' => '0',
    'use_for_shipping' => '1',
);

$quote->getBillingAddress()
        ->addData($billingAddress);

$quote->getShippingAddress()
        ->addData($billingAddress)
        ->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway')
        ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo')
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectTotals();

$quote->setCheckoutMethod('guest')
            ->setCustomerId(null)
            ->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
            ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);

$quote->getPayment()->importData( array('method' => 'checkmo'));

$quote->save();

$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
```

Comment: how can i select 100 nos of products to customer

Comment: /* create order for guest customer */

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

    $lsit_od_id = array('7125','7088','7089');
    How can i create order for my registered customer....

Comment: ye, you can just add customer id in the order and make order as registered user order,the above code is for registered user only.

Comment: is possible to give a custom price for my products?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146738/discussion-between-rathinam-and-manoj-chaurasia).

Comment: could you pls join chat

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146738/discussion-between-rathinam-and-manoj-chaurasia