# create order programmatically - mage.php

Tags: forms, magento, magento-1.8

Im trying to create an order programmatically using Branko code: http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/ and a modification of it made by devin http://www.devinrolsen.com/creating-magento-orders-programmatically/ .

Including that code in my form controller in magento Im constantly receiving the following errors in /var/log/system and error page when I submit the form:

```
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in Varien.php on line 71
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in Varien.php on line 73
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in Varien.php on line 75
```

I checked and that code request to include the correct path to require_once '../../Mage.php'; and Mage::app("default") declaration on it. doing that I receive the following errors:

```
ERR (3): Notice: Constant DS already defined  in Mage.php on line 27
ERR (3): Notice: Constant PS already defined  in Mage.php on line 28
ERR (3): Notice: Constant BP already defined  in Mage.php on line 29
```

I cannot make that code work. orders are not processed and error page appear each time i submit the form.

its necessary to include mage.php in the code. not including mage.php leads to an error because not mage environment is defined (like cookie)?.. 
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please include

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

Please uesd below link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474489/import-orders-in-magento-through-csv
```

Comment: you can use below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474489/import-orders-in-magento-through-csv

Comment: but i believe it has to do with session cookies